# Probably improbable

Tags: probability

So its way to long since I did any probability calculation and got myself a bit confused.

Problem is as follows.

I have $1000$ slots and $30$ balls. The balls are randomly put into the slots but just one ball in each. Now what is the probability of having $17$ OR MORE in the first $40$ slots?

How do you set this up. I guess the probability of finding a ball in a slot is about $3\%$.

Comment: To a first approximation, you can neglect the fact that only one ball can go in a slot. Then you have a binomial distribution: each ball independently has probability $40/1000=0.04$ to be in the first 40 slots, and there are 30 balls. So you want the probability that a binomial variable with parameters $n=30$ and $p=0.04$ is at least $17$. This is tedious but routine to calculate. In MATLAB the answer is actually so close to $0$ that it rounds off to zero. Your actual calculation is more difficult, I'm not sure of a short way to do it.

Comment: @Ian, $17$ is a substantial fraction of $40$, so I don't think you can neglect the assumption that only one ball can go in a slot.  (I.e., what happens to your argument if $40$ is replaced by $4$ but $17$ remains the same?)

Comment: @BarryCipra You're right, there is quite a bit of loss there. "A first approximation" is not always "a good approximation". :)

Comment: Use the hypergeometric distribution for the exact answer. You will be summing for k = 17 to 30 (or alternatively 1 minus the sum from 0 to 16). You will be choosing k slots out of 40, and 30-k slots out of the other 960. That's just a product of 2 combinations. Then divide by the total ways to choose 30 out of 1000.

I don't know what computational facilities you are allowed to use, but if you can use R, this can be done in seconds in 2 lines. The probability is extremely tiny.

Comment: Yeah I was going to say, if you have 10 placed (about half) the probability goes from $\frac{40}{1000} = 0.04$ to $\frac{30}{1000} = 0.03$ which isn't a large absolute difference but is 75% of the original probability.

Comment: The binomial idea is high by over 2 orders of magnitude.  Like 10e-16 vs. 10e-18.  Those shouldn't be too tiny for MATLAB though.

Comment: @BruceZ It is without using the 'upper' option.

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate a large factorial?  That isn't necessary.

Comment: Considering that (at least according to my Monte Carlo sim) the expected number of balls in the first 40 slots is about 1.2, the probability of getting 17 or more would essentially be zero (which it would appear @BruceZ sort of confirmed).  I'm not sure what type of physical experiment this might correspond to that could ever hope to find a success (I mean LHC has a collision every 25 nanoseconds).  At that rate, with $p \approx 10^{-18}$, you wouldn't expect to see a success for about 800 years.

Comment: @jared It's good that it is unlikely. what it really is about is nand flash. they can have up to 3% bad blocks from factory of a total of 1024. normally you hide the bad blocks like in ssd disks. but I have a system where about 3M (24 blocks)of data is stored on a fixed 5MB(40 blocks) position on the nand.

Comment: @kenjo Then you don't need an exact answer...in fact an order of magnitude answer would suffice in this situation.

Comment: @jared sure but for personal interest I was more interested in how to solve it than the actual solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using the hypergeometric distribution for the exact answer:
$$P(\text{at least 17 in first 40}) = \sum_{k=17}^{30}\frac{{40 \choose k}{960 \choose 30-k}}{1000 \choose 30} \approx 3.23598\text{ x }10^{-18}$$

Evaluating in R:

```
> k = 17:30
> sum(choose(40,k)*choose(960,30-k))/choose(1000,30)
[1] 3.23598e-18
```

There's also this one.

```
> phyper(16,40,960,30,lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 3.23598e-18
```

Comment: I would like to see how far you actually have to go to get that value.  Because the first term is $\binom{960}{13}\times \binom{40}{17} \approx 7.7248002\text{e}39$ whereas the last term is $\binom{40}{30}\times \binom{960}{0} = 847660528$ and there is no way that this term will contribute to the final answer.  Indeed the first term gives a _very_ approximate answer: $3.1794428\text{e-}18$

Comment: @Jared First 2 terms give 3.235154e-18.  First 3 give  3.23597e-18.

Comment: @Jared you only need to go to 25 to exhaust the limit of double precision at 15 digits.  3.23597952552551e-18